# Can I pass an image on the SecondViewController to the FirstViewController?

Tags: swift, image, collections, viewcontroller, back

From First ViewController I press a Button and open a SecondViewController that view a collection of Image, when I tap on image the view show a full screen image and return at the collection View. Can I pass the image to the first (starting) viewcontroller to use it as a background?

---

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func returnHome(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "backToHome", sender: nil)
    }
    var images = ["bg13", "bg11", "bg6", "bg10", "bg12", "bg5", "bg3", "bg4", "bg2", "bg7", "bg8", "bg9", "bg1", "bg14"]
    // ...
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let imageViewCollection = UIImageView(image:UIImage(named: images [indexPath.item]))
        imageViewCollection.frame = self.view.frame
        imageViewCollection.backgroundColor = .black
        imageViewCollection.contentMode = .top
        imageViewCollection.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissFullscreenImage))
        imageViewCollection.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        imageViewCollection.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        imageViewCollection.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.view.addSubview(imageViewCollection)
    }      
    @objc func dismissFullscreenImage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Comment: You should fix the code. Everything is not wrapped in code-block. Hard to read (especially on a phone)

Comment: It's unclear (to me) what your navigation stack is. In your `SecondViewController` you are doing a `performSegue` too...? BackToHome? Is this an unwind segue? Also, what *specifically* are you trying to pass back to `firstViewController`? There most definitely is a way to do this using segues. But last (and most importantly) - if all this second VC is for is to **select** a background image for the first VC, why not *present* it from the first and use delegation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Delegate** to pass the image to the first view controller.
Write this protocol on the top of the Second View Controller.

```
protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate: NSObject {
    func sendToFirstViewController(image: UIImage)
}
```

Then create a variable inside Second View Controller

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    ....
    weak var customDelegate: SecondViewControllerDelegate?
    ....
}
```

Call this from **collectionView:didSelectItemAt:indexPath** method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let image = UIImage(named: images [indexPath.item])
    customDelegate?.sendToFirstViewController(image: image)
    ...
}
```

In the First viewController, in where you instantiate the second view controller, put this line

```
secondVc.customDelegate = self
```

then create an extension to implement the delegate method

```
extension FirstViewController: SecondViewControllerDelegate {
    func sendToFirstViewController(image: UIImage){
        // use this image as your background
    }
}
```